# Read input values contained in divs separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, function

my html looks like this:

```
<div id="Section1" class="divFiles">

<input type="text" name="file">

<input type="text" name="file">

<input type="text" name="file">

<input type="text" name="file">

</div>

  <div id="Section2" class="divFiles">      

<input type="text" name="file">

<input type="text" name="file">

<input type="text" name="file">

<input type="text" name="file">

</div>
```

I want to generate a list of objects with two properties: `key`, and `listTitles`, key is just the id of the `div`, and `listTitles` is a list of every value that is on the `input` fields. I don't have any problem retrieving the id of every div separately, but I'm not sure of which is the correct way to read by div all the values contained in their children `inputs`.
My goal is to have this results:

```
{key: Section1, listTitles: inputValue1Div1, inputValue2Div1, inputValue2Div1, inputValue2Div1 },
{key: Section2, listTitles: inputValue1Div2, inputValue2Div2, inputValue2Div2, inputValue2Div2 }
```

I'm using this code that is retrieving only the `divs id`, the problem is to fill the `listTitles` property with the input value fields of the current div. What I need to change?

```
    var divElements = $(".divFiles");
    var tests = [];
     $.each(divElements, function () {           
     tests.push({ 'key': $(this).attr('id'), 'listTitles':$.each(JSON.parse($(this).children("input[name=file]").val()))});
     })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it. Use `.map().get()` instead.

```js
var divElements = $(".divFiles");
var tests = [];

$.each(divElements, function() {
  tests.push({
    'key': $(this).attr('id'),
    'listTitles': $(this).children("input[name=file]").map(function(i, elem) {
      return this.value;
    }).get()
  });
})

console.log(tests);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Section1" class="divFiles">
  <input type="text" name="file" value="a">
  <input type="text" name="file" value="b">
  <input type="text" name="file" value="c">
  <input type="text" name="file" value="d">
</div>

<div id="Section2" class="divFiles">
  <input type="text" name="file" value="e">
  <input type="text" name="file" value="f">
  <input type="text" name="file" value="g">
  <input type="text" name="file" value="h">
</div>
```